# S3/Cloudfront does not send image/jpeg Content-Type

Tags: amazon-s3, jpeg, amazon-cloudfront

I have a .jpg file stored in S3 and distributed using CloudFront. I can view the file when I download it, but I cannot view the file in Chrome or Safari. From what I can tell, I can't view the file in a browser because the Content-Type isn't getting sent despite the fact that I've set it in S3.

[image: The file's overview in the S3 console]

[image: The file's properties in the S3 console, which show that Content-Type is set to image/jpeg.]

[image: What I see when I click "Open" in the S3 console's "Overview" page]

[image: What I see when I enter a signed CloudFront url into the browser]

You can see what happens when you enter this signed CloudFront url into a browser. It should remain valid for roughly 24 hours after this post. https://media.development.doctheapp.com/claims/us-east-1:4877c3da-786a-4b3b-b1e0-c70bde0f9c4e741afc7c5a8304564963080a98e5675d09d1aca3d623911e34bd3b4eb0808579/300ae913-8f88-44b9-a4ab-e46d11133c76/receipt.jpg?Expires=1526533530&Signature=crnjhje1noP-7WfBMI6rMDPd-zdCAVKLaojFFNvxCZEdx0~EJHeqbL8oKwL64AULavekMHm~2r6vHto1d4IAt5eoLpbZR~q5PAfhSakte1iNNvuTxQ7q-mYOwoCemb5VD~bFXUBdrF1yiybaRHw-v6USbw53QZ2Qa4hfDkqgoEKwvEznBvR~sQnk5v-slX8~aJBhySS5XpkfdoE-yl8hh697xIyH~OliwrCg7h5iSkotwW9~EvTnLoVkXkuvru35eLhN4~gGMs3WDUAuucOl8JZdeg6CjAQQ~JWv6FJnb2wyvGrGJzOf70~8s08~qSqiCroyZfqUiZmw20eCIWXp4A__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJVSE2BEPIQCCPH6Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the original image is a TIFF file, not a JPEG. That's why you cannot see it in a browser but can open it upon download. The content type header is being sent correctly by Cloudfront if you look at the response headers.

Comment: Thanks, converting the file to a JPEG fixed it. For future reference, how were you seeing the correct content type header? I must have been looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I just downloaded the file on my Mac, opened in Preview, and tried exporting it. The export defaults to the actual file type. If you don't have a Mac, there are image format detection libraries out there for pretty much all languages. E.g. javascript: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type